# Различия OutputStream, BufferedWriter и FileWriter

Tags: java, android

Вот примеры вызова метода write каждого класса соответственно. Когда какой использовать, и чем они отличаются?

```
try {
   OutputStream fos = mContext.openFileOutput(FILE_DataRate, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   os.writeObject(answer);
   os.close();
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

---

```
try {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
    bw.write("Содержимое файла на SD");
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

---

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file_location_string);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("something");
```

Как я прочитал, `FileOutputStream` больше подходит для записи потоков необработанных байтов, таких как данные изображения. Для записи потоков символов рассмотрите возможность использования `FileWriter`.

И еще остается узнать насчет `BufferedWriter`.

Например, я заметил, что `OutputStream` не принимает на вход тип `File`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Напишу коротко:

`InputStram`/`OutputStream` - потоки читающие, пишущие байты. Читать и писать они могут все, т.к. все записано в байтах.

---

`Reader`/`Writer` - потоки обертки над `InputStram`/`OutputStream`. Читают и пишут символы (в символе может быть несколько байт).

Если посмотреть исходники реализаций (`FileWriter` в вашем случае), то можно увидеть создание `FileOutputStream`:

```
public FileWriter(String fileName) throws IOException {
    super(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
}
```

---

`BufferedReader`/`BufferedWriter` - наследник `Reader`/`Writer` добавляющий методы чтения и записи целых строк, а не отдельных символов.

Опять же если посмотреть исходники, то этот класс принимает в конструктор `Writer` объект:

```
 public BufferedWriter(Writer out)
```

---

`ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` - наследники и обертки `InputStram`/`OutputStream`. Предназначены для записи объектов в оборачиваемые потоки.

```
public ObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out)
```

---

Разница между `ObjectOutputStream` и `BufferedWriter` в том, что первый пишет объект в понятном для компьютера и java формате(не читаемом для человека), а второй пишет строки т.е. вы можете записать объект в удобном и читаемом для вас виде, но придется описать так же как его читать.

Comment: Скажите, а если писать в файл Json, то достаточно использовать BufferedWriter?

Comment: @Turalllb да. Если вы куда либо хотите писать строку текста, можно использовать BufferedWriter

Answer (score 5):

Ну если посмотреть внимательно, то второй и третий способ это суть один и тот же код, просто в третьем варианте вы записываете в FileWriter в отдельную переменную, а во-втором нет, то есть

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file_location_string);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write("something");
```

превращается в

```
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
out.write("something");
```

а это как раз вариант номер 2.

Значит весь вопрос только в чем отличие [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) от [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html). И тут нам приходит на помощь javadoc.

> [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) - Writes **text to a character-output stream, buffering characters** so as to provide for the efficient writing of
>   **single characters, arrays, and strings**.
>
> An [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) writes **primitive data types and graphs of Java
>   objects** to an `OutputStream`. The objects can be read (reconstituted)
>   using an `ObjectInputStream`.

То есть `BufferedWriter` умеет записывать только **строки или символы**, а `ObjectOutputStream` записывает **любые примитивные типы и сериализированные объекты**.

Соответственно, `BufferedWriter` используется для записи обычных текстовых файлов, а `ObjectOutputStream` для записи бинарного представления объектов Java (сериализации), на выходе будет совсем разный тип файлом и принимают они совсем разные сущности для записи.

Если вы откроете файл, записанный с помощью `ObjectOutputStream` в любом текстовом редакторе, то скорее всего среди обычного текста вы увидите бинарные символы (даже если писали только текст), а с помощью `BufferedWriter` вы ничего, кроме текста, по большому счету, записать не сможете.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю, что отличие `BufferedWriter` от `FileWriter` состоит в том, что `BufferedWriter` - это обёртка над `FileWriter`, которая не пишет данные непосредственно в файл после вызова метода write, а записывает их во временный буфер (с размером 8192 байт по умолчанию). Перезапись в файл происходит или если буфер заполнится, или если будет вызван метод flush или если поток закроется методом close.

Пример с `FileWriter` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file_location_string);
    fw.write("something");
    fw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {}
```