# В чем различие OutputStreamWriter и FileWriter?

Tags: java, потоки-данных

Честно гуглил. Нашел это: [OutputStreamWriter vs FileWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371154/outputstreamwriter-vs-filewriter/11371322). В ответах говорится вообще о различиях XXXInputStream и XXXOutputStream(хоть это было очень полезно, но это не то, что мне нужно).
По второй ссылке это: [Различия OutputStream, BufferedWriter и FileWriter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753359/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-outputstream-bufferedwriter-%D0%B8-filewriter). Тоже ответа я не нашел.

По сути:
Вот полный код класса:

```
public class FileWriter extends OutputStreamWriter {
    public FileWriter(String fileName) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    }

    public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(fileName, append));
    }

    public FileWriter(File file) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(file));
    }

    public FileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(file, append));
    }

    public FileWriter(FileDescriptor fd) {
        super(new FileOutputStream(fd));
    }

    public FileWriter(String fileName, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(fileName), charset);
    }

    public FileWriter(String fileName, Charset charset, boolean append) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(fileName, append), charset);
    }

    public FileWriter(File file, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(file), charset);
    }
    public FileWriter(File file, Charset charset, boolean append) throws IOException {
        super(new FileOutputStream(file, append), charset);
    }
}
```

Он реализует абсолютно все конструкторы `OutputStreamWriter`. И не добавляет ничего нового. Я в замешательстве.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это просто частный случай `OutputStreamWriter` для записи в файл. Такая обёртка.

Позволяет вам просто лишний раз не нагромождать ваш код вызовом конструктора `FileOutputStream`, просто его вызов инкапсулирован внутри `FileWriter`а

могло быть в вашем коде так:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file));
```

а будет так, короче, лаконичнее, понятнее:

```
new FileWriter(file);
```

Comment: Догадался, но вы меня опередили. Добавлю одно - эта обертка сужает функционал родителя. Новые абстракции на то и абстракции, что помогают программисту. Еще это дает нам уверенность, что в данном выходном потоке находится именно "поток файла".

Comment: Она не сужает его, а конкретизирует именно для задачи записи в файл.
Обычный `OutputStreamWriter` всегда в вашем распоряжении остаётся. В любом случае при объявлении переменной любого из этих типов объявлять её следует как интерфейс `Writer`, если заранее не известно что нужно более узкое примерение. А инициализировать уже конкретным `Writer`ом.